# ACH Payment Gateway with Intuit / Quickbooks

Tags: php, payment-gateway, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Does Intuit provide a payment gateway (similar to Stripe or Square) serviced by APIs which I can use to receive payments on my website (built with PHP)? Please note that I specifically want to use it to receive ACH payments ONLY. I will be using Stripe for the credit card transactions.

If such functionality exists then please provide a link to it's documentation or instruction how it might be accomplished. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Docs

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/get-started

#### Lib

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

#### Code

```
<?php

$name = 'Jane Doe';
$number = '856666';
$routing = '072403004';
$type = QuickBooks_Payments_BankAccount::TYPE_PERSONAL_CHECKING;
$phone = '860-634-1234';

$amount = 50;
$currency = 'USD';

$Payments = new QuickBooks_Payments($oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $sandbox);

$BankAccount = new QuickBooks_Payments_BankAccount($name, $number, $routing, $type, $phone);

if ($Transaction = $Payments->debit($Context, $BankAccount, $amount, $currency))
{
    //print_r($Transaction);

    print_r($Transaction);
}
else
{
    print('Error while debiting a bank account: ' . $Payments->lastError());
}
```

Comment: will this right away charge on the bank account? or there needs to be some verification done?

Comment: It will initiate the debit right away. Intuit does NOT require you to do an ACH verification like Stripe does (Stripe requires either microdeposits or Plaid). It's still a good idea for you to do some base level of validation yourself to protect yourself against fraud and/or incorrect account #s being entered.

Comment: Alright. Thank you Keith! Impressive work on the QuickBooks PHP DevKit package btw.